# Grunt command executed through Ant has slightly mangled output

Tags: node.js, ant, gruntjs

I have the following Ant build.xml script, which runs npm install and then grunt (this is a proof of concept to check if we can integrate grunt into our product through Ant, as a stopgap until we can add integrated support):

```
<project name="GruntTest" default="buildGrunt">
<description>Run Grunt as a test</description>
 <!-- ************************************************************** -->
  <!-- buildDemo : define the sequence of programs to be executed     -->
  <!-- ************************************************************** -->
  <target name="buildGrunt" depends="runNpm">
    <exec executable="cmd">
      <arg value="/c grunt"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="runNpm" depends="copySourceToTarget">
    <exec executable="cmd">
      <arg value="/c npm install"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

  <!-- ************************************************************** -->
  <!-- Copy all 'txt' files from the source to the target             -->
  <!--      end rename the extension to 'text'                        -->
  <!-- ************************************************************** -->
  <target name="copySourceToTarget">
    <copy todir="${target}" includeEmptyDirs="true">
      <fileset dir="${source}"  includes="*.*"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${target}/src/test" includeEmptyDirs="true">
     <fileset dir="${source}/src/test"  includes="*.*"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${target}/src/server" includeEmptyDirs="true">
      <fileset dir="${source}/src/server"  includes="*.*"/>
    </copy>
  </target> 
</project>
```

This is the Gruntfile.js script:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            options: {
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',

            },
            build: {
                src: 'src/server/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
                dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
            }
        },
        nodeunit: {
            all: ['src/test/*_test.js']
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-nodeunit');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'nodeunit']);

};
```

This provides the following output to the console when executed from the VScode Terminal:

```
copySourceToTarget:
     [copy] Copying 8 files to E:\ikan\alm\webtest_environments\vs_code\CONTBUILD\BUILD\target\181
     [copy] Copied 1 empty directory to 1 empty directory under E:\ikan\alm\webtest_environments\vs_code\CONTBUILD\BUILD\target\181
     [copy] Copying 1 file to E:\ikan\alm\webtest_environments\vs_code\CONTBUILD\BUILD\target\181\src\test
     [copy] Copying 1 file to E:\ikan\alm\webtest_environments\vs_code\CONTBUILD\BUILD\target\181\src\server

runNpm:
     [exec] added 630 packages in 23.676s
     [exec] npm WARN VSCode-Workspace@1.0.0 No repository field.
     [exec] 

buildGrunt:
     [exec] Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
     [exec] >> 1 file created 293 B â†’ 255 B
     [exec] 
     [exec] Running "nodeunit:all" (nodeunit) task
     [exec] Testing server_test.js..OK
     [exec] >> 3 assertions passed (8ms)
     [exec] 
     [exec] Done.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 27 seconds
```

If I run grunt directly, it gives the following output:

```
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
>> 1 file created 293 B → 255 B

Running "nodeunit:all" (nodeunit) task
Testing server_test.js..OK
>> 3 assertions passed (8ms)
```

Done.

As you can see, the uglify task has an arrow which displays properly in the grunt command, but when it's output to the ant output, it displays as  `B ÔåÆ` which is not what I want. I'm not sure what causes this, probably something to do with my console encoding, but I don't know for sure.

Is there a way to make the arrow display properly?